# Magento setText action doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9

From a working (layout, block, etc) webpage, I want to change the

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/script.js</name></action>
```

To something like

```
<block type="core/text" name="script_js">
    <action method="setText">
        <text><![CDATA[<script src="/skin/frontend/the_template/default/js/script.js?v=1"></script>]]></text>
    </action>
</block>
```

I even tried just putting a random string side the `<text>` node and it still doesn't work, it doesn't show anything.

The `reference` is a custom (working) block.